# How to add a website to the Apache Web Server

Tags: apache

I have installed a the following Drupal distribution on an Ubuntu virtual machine at `/var/www/html`.

https://www.drupal.org/project/social

The Composer script installs the project at `/var/www/html/project-folder` and index.php can be found in `/var/www/html/project-folder/html`.

Within the file `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf` I have changed the document root to `/var/www/html/project-folder/html'.

Now when I visit the IP Address for the server, it does load the homepage of the PHP based website, but all of the links to other pages are broken, and none of the images can be found.

What is the correct way to add a new site to the Apache web server? Should a VirtualHost be used, or is it better to change the document root?

**/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/project-folder/html

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: did you run `sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf` and `sudo a2ensite 000-default.conf` and `sudo service apache2 reload` in that order after changing configuration in 000-default.conf?  Can you also add the 000-default.conf in your question?

Comment: No, but is there any chance that would break anything? And is it better to change the document root (seen above), or to create a new virtual host?

Comment: Best practice would be to create a new config file, copy it from the 000-default.conf, change the directory path and also add the domain you will be using (you have to add this domain and IP in you local machine hostfile - from where you will be accessing the website unless you have the dns records set already).  No those commands should not break anything you can have a try with those commands first. If you still have any issues proceed with creating a new virtualhost configuration file.